# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN Laravel y Digital Ocean dejó de funcionar

Tags: laravel, dominio, godaddy, digitalocean, certbot

Necesito de vuestra ayuda. Tengo Laravel en Digital Ocean y ayer quise configurar Certbot para HTTPS, siguiendo los siguientes pasos de instalación:

```
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

Al principio me indico un error:

> Problem in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ tried to insert directive ssl_ciphers

Ahí empezó mi preocupación, luego de varias pruebas de **reinstalación de Certbot** fuí a GoDaddy y vi que los DNS estaban mal, se vé que Certbot por alguna razón que desconozco me los cambió. De hecho llamé a GoDaddy y me dijieron que ellos no tienen ningun problema con el dominio y que todo está bien.

Repetí los pasos de reinstalación cambiando el server name en:

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name todocontenidoweb;
server_tokens off;
root /home/forge/todocontenidoweb.com/public;
```

Dejando la información como estaba antes.

Repito todos los pasos me figuraron bien. Pero el sitio dejo de andar. Alguien sabe que podría hacer? el error dice DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

Comment: Este comentario no te va a servir de nada ahora, pero para la próxima seguro que si: **haz backup antes de tocar nada**.

Comment: Hola Benito, tengo Backups de todo. De hecho volví todo al paso anterior, pero algo quedo mal y no me levanta el sitio. Gracias igual!

Comment: No me refiero a backups de las cosas... si no a un backup de la máquina como tal. Que te deje la máquina en exactamente el estado que estaba. Es la manera más segura de instalar cosas que pueden causar estragos :)

Comment: Si gracias Benito! tenés razón! después de ver que puedo hacer con esto que ya llevo dos días, voy a seguir tu consejo. Muchas gracias!